# Footnote on wrong page paragraph

Tags: citing, footnotes, page

I have question regarding a footnote problem. So, my latex document looks like this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[citestyle=authortitle-ibid,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literature.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\itshape}
\usepackage[bottom,para]{footmisc}


\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Then, in my first paragraph I have a footnote citation using

```
\footcite[Some text][page]{Citation}
```

After pdflatex+biblatex+pdflatex, the first paragraph splits onto page 2, however, the footnote remains on page 1. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Show a real example that demonstrates the problem. If possible replace the bib and the cite by something from biblatex-examples.bib.

Comment: One solution is to put \footnotemark in the paragraph and \footcitetext AFTER the paragraph (with blank lines above and below).